# What are the security effects of giving the IIS_IUSRS a Full Control permission?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, iis

What are the the security effects of giving the IIS_IUSRS a Full Control permission on the root folder of ASP.NET websites?

Why can't I give the full control permission to IUSR only, which is part of IIS_IUSER group?

Any answer clarifies this conflict, is really appreciated.

Comment: Any user in that group (other websites) will be able to view/modify any file in the foot folder and below. This is typically undesired, but in some scenarios may actually be desired. By giving a single user such as IUSR permissions, it allows you to keep your sites isolated and use multiple users that may share the same base access to C:\Inetpub but not anywhere else other than the individual sites like C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\site1.com\ owned by IUSR1 and C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\site2.com\ owned by IUSR2 for best practices.

Comment: @BrockHensley, Say, the IIS_IUSRS have a full Control permission for all websites and we have site1 and site2, Do you mean that site1 users will be able to view/modify any file in site2? This should be handled by IIS itself, Right?

Answer (score 22):

It is easy to confuse IUSR and IIS_IUSRS because of their names but these are two different things:

1. IIS_IUSRS is the group for IIS Worker Process Accounts. This means the identity that the application pool itself runs under.
2. IUSR is the anonymous user identity. That means the identity that IIS believes to be the user who is accessing the site. This user is not a member of the IIS_IUSRS group by default.

> In IIS 7.0, a built-in account (IUSR) replaces the IUSR_MachineName account. Additionally, a group that is named IIS_IUSRS replaces the IIS_WPG group. [...] The IUSR account resembles a network or local service account. The IUSR_MachineName account is created and used only when the FTP 6 server that is included on the Windows Server 2008 DVD is installed. If the FTP 6 server is not installed, the account is not created.
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981949

IIS_IUSRS is a built-in group has access to all the necessary file and system resources so that an account, when added to this group, can seamlessly act as an application pool identity.

Read [similar thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/179627/how-come-when-i-add-iis-iusrs-rw-access-to-a-folder-it-doesnt-automatically-al) which explains why giving an access to IIS_IUSRS has different effect than giving same access to IUSR:

[Here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/140/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis-7/) is a good documentation about groups and users used in IIS 7.

By default, IIS_IUSRS has only read & execute (and as a result list folder contents) permissions on the wwwroot. The full control might be too much.

Answer (score 12):

Imagine a website that allows users to upload arbitrary files, that has a bug which causes such files to be saved in the application directory.

In this case, an attacker can upload an aspx file with arbitrary code, overwrite your web.config file, etc.

Far better to give readonly access to the root folder, and only give full control to specific folders that you know won't contain executable code, for example subfolders of App_Data.

Comment: I'd expand the answer to include read and review privileges. All connection strings, db names, web remote services exposed. Like giving the keys to your house.

Comment: However, the best option would be to move upload to temporary folder instead of any folder below application root.

Comment: @Joe, Is that so? What kind of user will be able to upload when giving IIS_IUSERS a full permission? Website visitors? would you please help with more details about this conflict.